# Issues trying to RDC into Win7 domain member

Tags: rdp

I have one workstation Win 7 Pro, that we can't RDC to ONLY WHEN IT'S CONFIGURED IN THE DOMAIN, regardless of the logaon with IP or DNS Name, using Admin user ID for domain and even the local machine (logging on as Domanname\username).

When the workstation is taken out of the Domain (I talked an end user through how to make the change settings) changed to Workgroup: Workgroup, then and only then can I RDC from the domain controller using a local machine RDP (TS) user ID.

The remote machine's firewall is turned off.  All the local machine and domain named users were set up in the RDP Group and/or Administrators, and I even manually gave Local Policy permission to these groups/users.  Still I can't RDP from the Domain controller to the workstation.

I have several workstations in the domain, that are on different subnets (i.e., 10.10.2.0, 10.12.2.0, and so forth, and they all work, and all have Win7 Pro.

I've read numerous threads but can't seem to find an answer.  The workstation is at a site that's 3-hours away and this is proving to be a great problem.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a group policy to deny remote desktop.  Here is the corresponding registry value that you can check to determine if this is the case:

```
Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services  
Value: fDenyTSConnections
```

If it is set, the system will not be listening on `0.0.0.0:3389` or `[::]:3389`.  The system monitors this registry value in real time, so if you do find it set to 1, as soon as you set it to zero the system should start listening on 3389.

This setting may also be set independently of a GPO.  In that case, the location is:

```
Key: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\
```

Comment: I'll check this and see if it's a problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I wound up using 3d party app (EaseUS) disk copy, reset the machine name etc, Major issue I had was with Symantec Ghost 15 not working like previous versions where you could do a disk-to-disk copy (unless you want to by another Symantec app!!!) Machine also has a PERC310 SCSI RAID controller for 1 HDD.  Why Dell did this for 1 drive is beyond me.  HDD could just use the integrated I/O.  PERC310 driver didn't want to work with many 3d party apps so I used a dock station to copy.